# SQL simple request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table looks like:

```
ID  | Advert_id  | Iso_code
----|------------|-----------
1   | 22         | en_US
2   | 22         | de_DE
3   | 11         | zh_CE
4   | 11         | nl_NL
```

I need to return `ID` for example I have `Advert_ID = 22` with `ID` 1 and 2 with `iso_code = en_US` and `de_DE` but if `Advert_ID` have `iso_code = en_US` return only `id = 1` if not return all ID ( `Advert_ID = 11` doesn't has `iso_code = en_US` so return `Id` 3 and 4)

Comment: What type of database did you use?

Comment: Sorry guys, sql-server

Comment: So maybe you want `select id from table where Advert_ID = 22 and iso_code = 'en_US'`?

Comment: Ok that was only example, I need to select all "Advarte_ID" and check iso_code if = 'en_US" return only ID with 'en_US'

Comment: My comment is an example as well. Modify as needed.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment :

> I need to select all "Advarte_ID" and check iso_code if = 'en_US" return only ID with 'en_US' .

If I understand you verry well, that will help :

```
SELECT ID
FROM YourTablName
WHERE iso_code = 'en_US';
```

That will return only `Advert_ID`s which have `iso_code = 'en_US'.

**Update:**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE iso_code = 'en_US')
BEGIN
SELECT ID
FROM YourTablName
WHERE iso_code = 'en_US';
END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SELECT ID
      FROM YourTable;
    END
```

Comment: ok, but I need to return also ID where iso_code is not equal 'en_US'

Comment: So select all the IDs , in the comment you say **return only ID with en_US'**

Comment: If iso_code has en_US return https://scr.hu/P1B54o if not return https://scr.hu/LrV5vo // I need to select all "Advarte_ID" and check iso_code if = 'en_US" return only ID with 'en_US' BUT if iso_code doesn't has en_US return all ID which it has

Comment: That's what I want sorry but I don't have idea how can I present it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `or not exists()`

```
select *
from t
where (t.iso_code = 'en_US' 
     or not exists (
        select 1 
        from t as i
        where t.Advert_id = i.Advert_id
          and i.iso_code = 'en_US')
      )
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/SGH43248

returns:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | advert_id | iso_code |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |        22 | en_US    |
|  3 |        11 | zh_CE    |
|  4 |        11 | nl_NL    |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Not exactly but It can help me